# Why is my monitor showing a blue/purple discoloration?

Tags: windows-10, display, colors

I just got a LG 24ML44B-B LED monitor. On 2 different Windows 10 computers, I have connected the monitor using HDMI. With both computers, the monitor exhibits a blue/purple discoloration with a lot of pixels flashing different colors. This happened with a desktop computer using the LG as the only monitor, and with a laptop computer duplicating the screen and extending the screen to the LG monitor.

For example, here's what my laptop screen looks like:

[image]

And here's what the duplicated screen to the LG monitor looks like:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you install the LG Monitor drivers?  .....  https://www.lg.com/us/support/software-firmware-drivers.  That may help. LG Monitors are not anywhere as good as Viewsonic or comparable.

Comment: I just tried that, and the driver setup program said "Driver installation success". But it didn't fix the problem, and Device Manager still shows "Generic PnP Monitor" for all screens attached to the laptop (including a Viewsonic monitor with no problems).

Comment: I am not sure what else. I put an LG monitor on a Windows 10 desktop as a stop gap measure. All washed out. I replaced the machine with a new desktop machine and got a ViewSonic monitor and colors are rich and deep. Very nice.

Comment: Have you tried a different HDMI cable?

Comment: Turn off HDR, could be forcing HDR or more than 8 bits per pixel to display that does not support it.

Comment: First check cables. Can you test it deferent mode, how does it look at bootup? And no, this would never be a driver issue. Monitor drivers are only to optimize color profiles or provide special Freq/resolution. Never this much color difference.

Comment: @AndrewMorton A different HDMI cable resulted in the same problem.

Comment: @Justme The only HDR settings I see are under "Video playback", and they are already disabled.

Comment: Have you got anything other than HDMI to connect with? I'd suspect it's DOA, but checking another connection type would give you better ammunition to send it back. I note from the spec it only has HDMI & VGA, which probably makes it quite an old model.

Comment: @Tetsujin VGA has the same problem. I will be returning this monitor.